# Evaluation of an integral using Mathematica or otherwise

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I need to find a closed form (in terms of known functions) using Mathematica or otherwise of $$\Re\left(\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac
{1-x}{\sqrt{-i-x^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{-i-x^2}}\ dx\right)$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit and $\Re$ denotes the real part. I tried a code on Wolfram cloud as
`Re[Integrate[ArcTan[(1-x)/(-x^2-I)^(1/2)]/(-x^2-I)^(1/2), {x, 1/2, 1}]]` but did not get any result.

We also have a similar integral having a closed form $$\int\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac
{x}{\sqrt{-i-x^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{-i-x^2}}\ dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac
{x}{\sqrt{-i-x^2}}\right)\right]^2 +C$$
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you expecting a closed form to exist?

Comment: The sub `x == Sqrt[I] Sinh[u]` works...

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. But $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and in your substitution $x\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Max why $x\in\mathbb C$? Michael didn't claim that $u\in\mathbb R$...

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is just a number. You can get its value to any desired precision using [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)

```
int50 = Re[
  NIntegrate[ArcTan[(1 - x)/(-x^2 - I)^(1/2)]/(-x^2 - I)^(1/2), {x, 1/2, 1}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 50]]

(* -0.041203512171872067789770454057244867140767910178258 *)
```

You can convert this value to an approximate [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expression using [`RootApproximant`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html)

```
inta = int50 // RootApproximant

(* Root[-8 - 194 # + 9 #^2 + 120 #^3 - 134 #^4 - 166 #^5 - 27 #^6 - 33 #^7 + 
 133 #^8 - 141 #^9 - 331 #^10 + 147 #^11 - 232 #^12 - 337 #^13 + 294 #^14 - 
 69 #^15 + 4 #^16& , 1, 0] *)
```

The error from the approximation is

```
int50 - inta

(* 2.4*10^-50 *)
```

For lower levels of precision the `Root` expression can be converted to a radical representation with [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html)

```
inta16 = int50 // N[#, 16] & // RootApproximant // ToRadicals

(* -(641/1548) - (401911 7^(2/3) (1 - I Sqrt[3]))/(
 3096 (-334247855 + 1548 I Sqrt[143024447823])^(
  1/3)) - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (7 (-334247855 + 1548 I Sqrt[143024447823]))^(
  1/3))/3096 *)
```

This representation differs from the high precision result by

```
int50 - FullSimplify[inta16]

(* -2.055101683907310203909684997075172161*10^-15 *)
```

Note that the [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) converted the radical representation back to a `Root` expression. This avoids any imaginary artifacts resulting from numeric evaluation of the radical representation. For example,

```
int50 - inta16

(* -2.055101683907310203909684997075172161*10^-15 + 0.*10^-68 I *)
```

Comment: $(+1)$. But I am sorry, I need a closed form not a numerical value.

Answer (score 3):

Really some algebraic adventure.

The numerical result is

```
 NIntegrate[ ArcTan[(1 - x)/(-x^2 - I)^(1/2)]/(-x^2 - I)^(1/2), {x, 1/2, 1}]

 -0.0412035 + 0.105342 I

  TraditionalForm[ Re[Integrate[ ArcTan[(1 - x)/(-x^2 - I)^(1/2)]/(-x^2 - I)^(1/2), {x, 1/2, 1}]]]
```

$$\Re\left(\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{-x^2-i}}\right)}{\sqrt{-x^2-i}} \, dx\right)$$

We use the outer algebraic form as differential $dy$

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt(x^2+ i)} = \int dy$$

```
  (\[Integrate[ 1 /Sqrt[x^2 + I] == y) /. 
   { a_  Log[b_] + d_ Log[c_] :>  a Log[(b/c)] /; a + d == 0 } //
      FullSimplify

    2 y + Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])] == 0
```

solving for x and replacing in the argument by y

$$\text{PowerExpand}\left[\text{FullSimplify}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{-x^2-i}}\right)\text{/.}\, \left\{x\to \frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{-1} \sqrt{e^{-2 y}+e^{2 y}-2}\right\}\right]\right]$$

$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1} \left(1-\sqrt[4]{-1} \sinh (y)\right) \text{sech}(y)\right)$$

The indefinite integral is with resubstitution

```
   res = I Integrate[ArcTan[(-1)^(1/4) Sech[y] (1 - (-1)^(1/4) Sinh[y])],y] /.
      {y :> -1/2 Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])]}


I (-(1/2) ArcTan[ Sech[1/2 Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])]] ((-1)^(1/4) +
I Sinh[1/2 Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])]])] Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])] +
 1/8 (-2 \[Pi] ArcTanh[(1 + Sqrt[2]) Cot[ 1/4 (\[Pi] - I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]] -
     4 \[Pi] ArcTanh[  Sqrt[2] + I Tanh[1/4 Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])]]] +
 4 ArcTanh[(-1 + Sqrt[2]) Tan[  1/4 (\[Pi] - 
         I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]] (\[Pi] + 
     I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])]) +
  1/2 I Log[ 1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])]^2 - (\[Pi] - 
     8 I ArcTanh[(1 + Sqrt[2]) Cot[ 1/4 (\[Pi] - 
            I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]]) Log[((1/2 + 
         I/2) ((-1 - I) + Sqrt[2]) (1 + 
         I Cot[1/4 (\[Pi] - I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]))/
(-1 +  Sqrt[2] +  Cot[1/4 (\[Pi] -   I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])])] - 
(\[Pi] +   8 I ArcTanh[(1 + Sqrt[2]) Cot[  1/4 (\[Pi] - 
            I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]]) Log[-(((1/
           2 + I/2) ((-1 + I) + Sqrt[2]) (I +  Cot[1/4 (\[Pi] - 
               I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]))/(-1 + 
         Sqrt[2] + 
         Cot[1/4 (\[Pi] - 
             I Log[1 +  2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]))] + 
      (\[Pi] -      8 I ArcTanh[(1 + Sqrt[2]) Cot[ 1/4 (\[Pi] - I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]] +   8 I ArcTanh[(-1 + Sqrt[2]) Tan[            1/4 (\[Pi] -  I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]]) Log[(-1)^(
     1/4)/(2^(3/4) (1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2]))^(1/4)
        Sqrt[-1 - 
        I Sqrt[2]
          Sinh[1/2 Log[
            1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])]]])] + (\[Pi] + 
     8 I ArcTanh[(1 + Sqrt[2]) Cot[
         1/4 (\[Pi] - I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]] - 
     8 I ArcTanh[(-1 + Sqrt[2]) Tan[
         1/4 (\[Pi] - 
            I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]]) Log[((1/2 - 
       I/2) (1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2]))^(1/4))/(
    2^(1/4) Sqrt[-1 - 
      I Sqrt[2]
        Sinh[1/2 Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])]]])] + 
  4 I (PolyLog[
      2, -(((1 + I) (-1 + Sqrt[2] - 
          Cot[1/4 (\[Pi] - 
              I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]))/(
       Sqrt[2] (-1 + Sqrt[2] + 
          Cot[1/4 (\[Pi] - 
              I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])])))] - 
     PolyLog[2, -(((1 - I) (-1 + Sqrt[2] - 
          
          Cot[1/4 (\[Pi] - 
              I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])]))/(
       Sqrt[2] (-1 + Sqrt[2] + 
          Cot[1/4 (\[Pi] - 
              I Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])])])))])))
```

No guarantee for failure free copy and paste here!

Result:

```
   Subtract @@ (res /. {{x -> 1}, {x -> 1/2}} // N)

    0.0412035 + 0.105342 I
```

There will be a wrong sign somewhere in the simplifications, I suspect.

What may be the reason to produce such an algebraic monster just to get a number?

Comment: $(+1)$ Elegant answer.  I did not understand that how did you write: "We use the outer algebraic form as differential $dy$

     (\[Integrate[ x /Sqrt[x^2 + I] == y) /. 
       { a_  Log[b_] + d_ Log[c_] :>  a Log[(b/c)] /; a + d == 0 } //
          FullSimplify

        2 y + Log[1 + 2 I x (-x + Sqrt[I + x^2])] == 0 ?

Comment: Also why do we have the real part in the final answer with opposite sign as the initial answer but the imaginary part of final answer as same as the initial one?

Comment: I changed the sign under the square root and put an I in front, maybe  its not quite correct.  There was a typo with an x instead of  an dx in the substitution that has to be discarded in Integrate; corrected.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. You wrote $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt(x^2+ i)} = \int dy$$ Can we not do this with a sign as in our question $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt(-x^2- i)} = \int dy$$? Will this give us the sign we want in the final answer?

Comment: You are right. In complex numbers we do not have $\sqrt{zw}=\sqrt{z} \sqrt{w}$

Comment: Please edit your answer so that we get the required sign. I will with utmost respect accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

This is just a simplification of Roland's method using `IntegrateChangeVariables` that produces more compact results

First define the integrand:

```
integrand[x_]=ArcTan[(1 - x)/Sqrt[-I - x^2]]/Sqrt[-I - x^2];
```

I tried for a long time to find a good substitution, but it looks like Roland's suggestion works perfectly. Using $y\to \log \left(\sqrt{-2 i x^2-2 \sqrt{-x^2 \left(x^2+i\right)}+1}\right)$ seems to work pretty well using `IntegrateChangeVariables`:

```
ySub = Log[Sqrt[-2 I x^2 - 2 Sqrt[-x^2 (x^2 + I)] + 1]];
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][integrand[x], x], y, 
    y == ySub] // FullSimplify // PowerExpand;

indef = Activate[%] // FullSimplify
```

> `1/4 (-y (y -  4 ArcCoth[((1 + I) Cosh[y])/(Sqrt[2] + (1 + I) Sinh[y])] +  2 Log[1 + (-1)^(1/4) E^y] - 2 Log[1 + (-1)^(3/4) E^y]) -  2 PolyLog[2, -(-1)^(1/4) E^y] + 2 PolyLog[2, -(-1)^(3/4) E^y])`

And plug in the integration bounds, and
`ComplexExpand` the real part of the definite integral:

```
lowerBound = ySub /. x -> (1/2);
upperBound = ySub /. x -> 1;
def = (indef /. y -> upperBound) - (indef /. y -> lowerBound) // 
   FullSimplify;
rePart = 
 ComplexExpand[Re[def], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // FullSimplify //
   ToRadicals
```

> `1/64 (4 ArcTan[Sqrt[2 (1 + Sqrt[2])]]^2 +  12 ArcTan[1/2 Sqrt[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[17])]]^2 -  Log[5 + 4 Sqrt[2] - 2 Sqrt[2 (7 + 5 Sqrt[2])]]^2 -  3 Log[1/4 (5 + Sqrt[17] - 2 Sqrt[13/2 + (5 Sqrt[17])/2])]^2 +  4 Log[Abs[((1 - 2 I) - 2 Sqrt[-1 - I])^(-((I \[Pi])/2) +  Log[(-8 + 7 I) + 4 Sqrt[1 - 7 I]]) (1/ 2 ((2 - I) - Sqrt[-1 - 4 I]))^ Log[-(15/16) + I/2] (1 - Sqrt[1/17 - (4 I)/17])^ Log[1/2 ((-17 - 8 I) + Sqrt[221 + 272 I])]]] +  32 Re[PolyLog[2, I + Sqrt[-1 - I]] -  PolyLog[2, 1/2 (I + Sqrt[-1 - 4 I])] -  PolyLog[2, 1 - Sqrt[1 + I]] +  PolyLog[2, 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 I])]])`

Comparing to `NIntegrate` result:

```
nRePart = 
  Re[NIntegrate[integrand[x], {x, 1/2, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]];
rePart - nRePart
```

> `0.*10^-102`

Comment: The result is an analytic expression, not a closed-form expression. There is no advantage over the numeric result.

Comment: $(+1)$ Thanks for the elegant answer. So we use the substitution $y\to \log \left(\sqrt{-2 i x^2-2 \sqrt{-x^2 \left(x^2+i\right)}+1}\right)$ but then $$  \sqrt{-2 i x^2-2 \sqrt{-x^2 \left(x^2+i\right)}+1}=e^{y}    $$ Then do we have $x\in\mathbb{R}$? Because in the question the limits of integration of $x$ are real number between $1/2$ and $1$. I am afraid that by using the above substitution $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

A better course of analysis with permanent control is this way

```
      ArcTan[(1 - x)/Sqrt[-x^2 - I]]  1/Sqrt[-x^2 - I] //TrigToExp
```

$$\frac{i \log \left(1-\frac{i (1-x)}{\sqrt{-x^2-i}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{-x^2-i}}-\frac{i \log \left(1+\frac{i (1-x)}{\sqrt{-x^2-i}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{-x^2-i}}$$

The signs and I's can be eliminated carefully

```
     Plot[{
     ReIm[ Log[-1 + x + Sqrt[I + x^2]]/(2 Sqrt[I + x^2]) -   
             Log[1 - x + Sqrt[I + x^2]]/(2 Sqrt[I + x^2])], 
      ReIm[ ArcTan[(1 - x)/Sqrt[-x^2 - I]]  1/Sqrt[-x^2 - I]]}, 
    {x, 1/2,  1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.02], Red}, {Thickness[0.005], Black}}]
```

[image: comparing complex curves]

The first integrand  yields

```
      f1 = 1/2 \[Integral]Log[-1 + x + Sqrt[I + x^2]]/Sqrt[
I + x^2] \[DifferentialD]x
```

$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-x-\sqrt{x^2+i}+1\right)+\log \left(\sqrt{x^2+i}+x-1\right) \log \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+i}\right)\right)$$

The second seems to fail

```
    1/2 \[Integral]Log[1 - x + Sqrt[I + x^2]]/Sqrt[ I + x^2] \[DifferentialD]x
```

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\log \left(\sqrt{x^2+i}-x+1\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+i}} \, dx$$

but can be done trivially by

$$\text{f2}=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\log \left(\sqrt{x^2+i}+x+1\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+i}} \, dx\text{/.}\, \{x\to -x\}$$

$$-\frac{1}{2} \text{Li}_2\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+i}\right)$$

```
   f[x_] = f1 + f2

   D[f[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{\log \left(\sqrt{x^2+i}+x-1\right)-\log \left(\sqrt{x^2+i}-x+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2+i}}$$

```
  Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[f[x] - f[1/2]]], {x, 1/2, 1}]
```

[image: Complex line integral]

Compare to

```
   g = NDSolveValue[
       {h'[x] == ArcTan[(1 - x)/Sqrt[-x^2 - I]]  1/Sqrt[-x^2 - I],h[1/2] == 0},
         h, {x, 1/2, 1}]


     Plot[ReIm[{  g[x]}], {x, 1/2, 1}]
```

[image: Numerical complex line integral]